# DB2 and PHP on Windows (2003)

Tags: php, db2

I'm using Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2 on Windows Server 2003.

I need to comunicate with a DB2 IBM database via php.

The problem is that i've downloaded the PECL to DB2 IBM and pasted the file php_ibm_db2.dll on php/ext folder.
Then i've inserted on php.ini the extension ( extension=php_ibm_db2.dll ).
The apache is running php well, at least in can run pages with curl functions.
But my php info() doesn't show the extension for DB, and can't recognize db2_connect() function.

Yes i've already restarted apache.

What I'm missing?

To comunicate with a DB2 external database (not in that computer), do I need to install any IBM software?

Comment: Sweet fancy jesus literally everything you're running was End-of-Lifed ***YEARS*** ago. You need to upgrade literally everything you've mentioned, and probably most of what you *haven't* mentioned as well. ***DO IT NOW.***

Comment: I know but I can't. that's how the system is implemented. 
But tell me, assuming the same DB2 database on other machine, and using my laptop with windows 10 and xamp with php 5.6, How can I connect to that DB2 database? 
XAMP doesn't recognize (shows an error of library not found) my php_ibm_db2.dll for php 5.6 even activating it on php.ini. 
Do I need to install any stuff from IBM?

Comment: Yes you do need to install the DB2 client package.

Comment: Here's a great quote from a friend: "You can pretend to care about your users and help them run old versions of software or you can actually care about them and give them incentive to upgrade. Do the responsible thing, run supported software and encourage your users to as well."